# Best environment to do jscript development on Windows?

Tags: ide, javascript

I would need to create some webpages that are using jscript and different jscript libraries heavily and I will need to write a littlebit of code and debug it through to see if that works. I would like to know if there is an IDE exists on Windows jsut to do this or there is a combination of tools that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest [Visual Studio Web Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/), which you can easily configure to be a JScript debugger: http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx)

Since JScript [Microsoft dialect of ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion hands down the best JavaScript debugger available for windows is Visual Studio, unfortunately its far from free however the link that naivists posted allows you to use Visual Studio Express - Web Developer Edition (which is free) to do the same thing:

[How to debug JavaScript with Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/)

You could also look into using tools like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) (Firefox only) - these sorts of tools are very good at inspecting and tweaking the layout of the page, however I've always found the JavaScript debugger to be a little lacking.